# apache poi XSSFClientAnchor not positioning picture with respect to dx1, dy1, dx2, dy2

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am trying to add an image to excel using **apach-poi version *3.16***. I am able to do that with `HSSFWorkbook` and `XSSFWorkbook`. But when i am trying to add spacing for the image i.e if I set `dx1`, `dy1`, `dx2`, `dy2` coordinates on `XSSFClientAnchor` it is not taking effect. Same thing is working on `HSSFClientAnchor`. I am attaching both classes and corresponding excel file generated. Could you please help me how can i do achieve the same result using `XSSFClientAnchor`.

HSSF Class

```
package poisamples;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ClientAnchor.AnchorType;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPatriarch;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPicture;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class HSSFImage {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String imageFile = "test.png";
        String outputFile = "image-sutpid.xls";
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Image");
        HSSFClientAnchor anchor = new HSSFClientAnchor(100,100,100,100,(short)0, (short)0, (short)0, (short)3);

        sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 6000);

        anchor.setAnchorType(AnchorType.DONT_MOVE_AND_RESIZE);
        int index = sheet.getWorkbook().addPicture(imageToBytes(imageFile), HSSFWorkbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);

        HSSFPatriarch patriarch = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
        HSSFPicture picture = patriarch.createPicture(anchor, index);
        picture.resize();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        workbook.write(fos);
    }

    private static byte[] imageToBytes(String imageFilename) throws IOException {
        File imageFile;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos;
        int read;
        try {
            imageFile = new File(imageFilename);
            fis = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            while ((read = fis.read()) != -1) {
                bos.write(read);
            }
            return (bos.toByteArray());
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                try {
                    fis.close();
                    fis = null;
                } catch (IOException ioEx) {
                    // Nothing to do here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XSSF Class

```
package poisamples;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPicture;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ClientAnchor.AnchorType;

public class XSSFImage {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String imageFile = "test.png";
        String outputFile = "image-sutpid.xlsx";
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Image");
        XSSFClientAnchor anchor = new XSSFClientAnchor(100,100,100,100,0, 0, 0, 3);

        sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 6000);

        anchor.setAnchorType(AnchorType.DONT_MOVE_AND_RESIZE);
        int index = sheet.getWorkbook().addPicture(imageToBytes(imageFile), XSSFWorkbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);

        XSSFDrawing patriarch = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
        XSSFPicture picture = patriarch.createPicture(anchor, index);
        picture.resize();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        workbook.write(fos);
    }

    private static byte[] imageToBytes(String imageFilename) throws IOException {
        File imageFile;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos;
        int read;
        try {
            imageFile = new File(imageFilename);
            fis = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            while ((read = fis.read()) != -1) {
                bos.write(read);
            }
            return (bos.toByteArray());
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                try {
                    fis.close();
                    fis = null;
                } catch (IOException ioEx) {
                    // Nothing to do here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HSSF Result:

[image: HSSF Result Image]

XSSF Result:

[image: XSSF Result Image]

Image used:

[image: Test Image used]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems are the different strange measurement units which Microsoft is using and the fact that the binary file system `*.xls` and the Office Open XML `*.xlsx` are very  different not only in file storing but in general approaches also.

As mentioned in [ClientAnchor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/ClientAnchor.html): "Note - XSSF and HSSF have a slightly different coordinate system, values in XSSF are larger by a factor of Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL". But this is not the whole truth. The meaning of the `dx` and `dy` is totally different. In the binary file system `*.xls`, the values are dependent on the factor of `column-width` / `default column-width` and `row-height` /  `default row-height`. Don't ask me about the factor `14.75` used in my example. It is just trial&error.

To mention about your code is that if you wants resizing the picture to its native size, then only a one cell anchor is needed. This anchors the picture's upper left edge. A two cell anchor only is needed if the anchor shall determining the picture's size. Then the first cell in the anchor anchors the picture's upper left edge while the second cell  in the anchor anchors the picture's bottom right edge.

The following example uses the measurement unit `1/256th of a character width` for `dx` since column widths also are in this measurement unit. And it uses `point` as  measurement unit for `dy` since row heights also are in this measurement unit.

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ClientAnchor.AnchorType;
import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;

import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;

public class CreateExcelWithPictures {

 private static Picture drawImageOnExcelSheet(Sheet sheet, 
  int col1, int row1, int dx1/*1/256th of a character width*/, int dy1/*points*/,
  int col2, int row2, int dx2/*1/256th of a character width*/, int dy2/*points*/, 
  String pictureurl, int picturetype, boolean resize) throws Exception {

  int DEFAULT_COL_WIDTH = 10 * 256;
  float DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT = 12.75f;

  Row row = sheet.getRow(row1);
  float rowheight1 = (row!=null)?row.getHeightInPoints():DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT;
  row = sheet.getRow(row2);
  float rowheight2 = (row!=null)?row.getHeightInPoints():DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT;

  int colwidth1 = sheet.getColumnWidth(col1);
  int colwidth2 = sheet.getColumnWidth(col2);

  InputStream is = new FileInputStream(pictureurl);
  byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
  int pictureIdx = sheet.getWorkbook().addPicture(bytes, picturetype);
  is.close();

  CreationHelper helper = sheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();

  Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

  ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
  anchor.setAnchorType(AnchorType.DONT_MOVE_AND_RESIZE);

  anchor.setRow1(row1); //first anchor determines upper left position
  if (sheet instanceof XSSFSheet) {
   anchor.setDy1(dy1 * Units.EMU_PER_POINT);
  } else if (sheet instanceof HSSFSheet) {
   anchor.setDy1((int)Math.round(dy1 * Units.PIXEL_DPI / Units.POINT_DPI * 14.75 * DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT / rowheight1));
  }
  anchor.setCol1(col1); 
  if (sheet instanceof XSSFSheet) {
   anchor.setDx1((int)Math.round(dx1 * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL * Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH / 256f));
  } else if (sheet instanceof HSSFSheet) {
   anchor.setDx1((int)Math.round(dx1 * Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH / 256f * 14.75 * DEFAULT_COL_WIDTH / colwidth1));
  }

  if (!resize) {
   anchor.setRow2(row2); //second anchor determines bottom right position
   if (sheet instanceof XSSFSheet) {
    anchor.setDy2(dy2 * Units.EMU_PER_POINT);
   } else if (sheet instanceof HSSFSheet) {
    anchor.setDy2((int)Math.round(dy2 * Units.PIXEL_DPI / Units.POINT_DPI * 14.75 * DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT / rowheight2));
   }
   anchor.setCol2(col2);
   if (sheet instanceof XSSFSheet) {
    anchor.setDx2((int)Math.round(dx2 * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL * Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH / 256f));
   } else if (sheet instanceof HSSFSheet) {
    anchor.setDx2((int)Math.round(dx2 * Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH / 256f * 14.75 * DEFAULT_COL_WIDTH / colwidth2));
   }
  }

  Picture picture = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);

  if (resize) picture.resize();

  return picture;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");
  sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 6000/*1/256th of a character width*/);

  Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
  row.setHeightInPoints(100/*points*/);

  row = sheet.createRow(10);
  row.setHeightInPoints(50/*points*/);

  Picture picture;

  //two cell anchor in the same cell (B1) used without resizing the picture
  picture = drawImageOnExcelSheet(sheet, 
   1, 0, 1000/*1/256th of a character width*/, 10/*points*/, 
   1, 0, 5000/*1/256th of a character width*/, 90/*points*/, 
   "mikt1.png", Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, false);

  //one cell anchor (B3) used with resizing the picture
  picture = drawImageOnExcelSheet(sheet, 
   1, 2, 1000/*1/256th of a character width*/, 10/*points*/, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 
   "mikt1.png", Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, true);

  //two cell anchor (B10 to B12) used without resizing the picture
  picture = drawImageOnExcelSheet(sheet, 
   1, 9, 1000/*1/256th of a character width*/, 10/*points*/, 
   1, 11, 5000/*1/256th of a character width*/, 10/*points*/, 
   "mikt1.png", Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, false);

  if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("image-sutpid.xlsx"));
  } else if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
   workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("image-sutpid.xls"));
  }
  workbook.close();

 }

}
```

---

Found at least the definition of `dx` and `dy` for binary `*-xls` file format. It is defined in [2.5.193 OfficeArtClientAnchorSheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-xls/fd656a2c-d5ee-4171-8f65-17a08b9f2262).

`dx`: The value is expressed as 1024th’s of that cell’s width.

`dy`: The value is expressed as 256th’s of that cell’s height.

Having that, the code should be like so:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ClientAnchor.AnchorType;
import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;

import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;

public class CreateExcelWithPictures {

 private static Picture drawImageOnExcelSheet(Sheet sheet, 
  int col1, int row1, int dx1/*1/256th of a character width*/, int dy1/*points*/,
  int col2, int row2, int dx2/*1/256th of a character width*/, int dy2/*points*/, 
  String pictureurl, int picturetype, boolean resize) throws Exception {

  int DEFAULT_COL_WIDTH = 10 * 256;
  float DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT = 12.75f;

  Row row = sheet.getRow(row1);
  float rowheight1 = (row!=null)?row.getHeightInPoints():DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT;
  row = sheet.getRow(row2);
  float rowheight2 = (row!=null)?row.getHeightInPoints():DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT;

  int colwidth1 = sheet.getColumnWidth(col1);
  int colwidth2 = sheet.getColumnWidth(col2);

  InputStream is = new FileInputStream(pictureurl);
  byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
  int pictureIdx = sheet.getWorkbook().addPicture(bytes, picturetype);
  is.close();

  CreationHelper helper = sheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();

  Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

  ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
  anchor.setAnchorType(AnchorType.DONT_MOVE_AND_RESIZE);

  anchor.setRow1(row1); //first anchor determines upper left position
  if (sheet instanceof XSSFSheet) {
   anchor.setDy1(dy1 * Units.EMU_PER_POINT);
  } else if (sheet instanceof HSSFSheet) {
   anchor.setDy1((int)Math.round(dy1 * Units.PIXEL_DPI / Units.POINT_DPI * 256f / (rowheight1 * Units.PIXEL_DPI / Units.POINT_DPI)));
  }
  anchor.setCol1(col1); 
  if (sheet instanceof XSSFSheet) {
   anchor.setDx1((int)Math.round(dx1 * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL * Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH / 256f));
  } else if (sheet instanceof HSSFSheet) {
   anchor.setDx1((int)Math.round(dx1 * Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH / 256f * 1024f / (colwidth1 * Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH / 256f)));
  }

  if (!resize) {
   anchor.setRow2(row2); //second anchor determines bottom right position
   if (sheet instanceof XSSFSheet) {
    anchor.setDy2(dy2 * Units.EMU_PER_POINT);
   } else if (sheet instanceof HSSFSheet) {
    anchor.setDy2((int)Math.round(dy2 * Units.PIXEL_DPI / Units.POINT_DPI * 256f / (rowheight2 * Units.PIXEL_DPI / Units.POINT_DPI)));
   }
   anchor.setCol2(col2);
   if (sheet instanceof XSSFSheet) {
    anchor.setDx2((int)Math.round(dx2 * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL * Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH / 256f));
   } else if (sheet instanceof HSSFSheet) {
    anchor.setDx2((int)Math.round(dx2 * Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH / 256f * 1024f / (colwidth2 * Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH / 256f)));
   }
  }

  Picture picture = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);

  if (resize) picture.resize();

  return picture;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");
  sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 6000/*1/256th of a character width*/);

  Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
  row.setHeightInPoints(100/*points*/);

  row = sheet.createRow(10);
  row.setHeightInPoints(50/*points*/);

  Picture picture;

  //two cell anchor in the same cell (B1) used without resizing the picture
  picture = drawImageOnExcelSheet(sheet, 
   1, 0, 1000/*1/256th of a character width*/, 10/*points*/, 
   1, 0, 5000/*1/256th of a character width*/, 90/*points*/, 
   "mikt1.png", Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, false);

  //one cell anchor (B3) used with resizing the picture
  picture = drawImageOnExcelSheet(sheet, 
   1, 2, 1000/*1/256th of a character width*/, 10/*points*/, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 
   "mikt1.png", Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, true);

  //two cell anchor (B10 to B12) used without resizing the picture
  picture = drawImageOnExcelSheet(sheet, 
   1, 9, 1000/*1/256th of a character width*/, 10/*points*/, 
   1, 11, 5000/*1/256th of a character width*/, 10/*points*/, 
   "mikt1.png", Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, false);

  if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("image-sutpid.xlsx"));
  } else if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
   workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("image-sutpid.xls"));
  }
  workbook.close();

 }

}
```

But then it would be better having all lengths in measurement unit pixel to avoid the conversion from pt and/or 256'th of a character width to pixels. See [Why the same image export excel using HSSFWorkbook can use SXSSFWorkbook can not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76966076/why-the-same-image-export-excel-using-hssfworkbook-can-use-sxssfworkbook-can-not) for example.