# How to change the color of the comment indicator using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, apache-poi

i'm working on an accounting software where we generate and receive excel files as input, in each file there are headers, some headers need a description so we add it as a cell comment, when the user uploads a file we parse it and validate each cell, when a cell is invalid we return the file with a comment on that cell explaining what's wrong

like this:
[image]

the problem is I want the comments that are on the headers to be green and not red (which is the default color apparently)

here's the method that we use to add a comment on a cell

```
public static void setComment(Cell cell, String commentString) {
    CreationHelper factory = cell.getSheet().getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();
    ClientAnchor anchor = factory.createClientAnchor();
    anchor.setCol1(cell.getColumnIndex());
    anchor.setCol2(cell.getColumnIndex() + NumberConstant.THREE);
    anchor.setRow1(cell.getRow().getRowNum());
    anchor.setRow2(cell.getRow().getRowNum() + NumberConstant.THREE);
    Drawing drawing = cell.getSheet().createDrawingPatriarch();
    Comment comment = cell.getCellComment();
    if (comment == null) {
        comment = drawing.createCellComment(anchor);
    }
    comment.setString(factory.createRichTextString(commentString));
    cell.setCellComment(comment);
}
```

when looking around I found [this link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2253-excel-change-comment-indicator-color.html) which apparently gets the job done but it's in VB and not using Apache POI

Comment: I'm not sure you can actually change the color of the indicator. That VBA approach is just adding a triangle shape over top. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: if that's possible using Apache POI then sure

Answer (score 1):

As stated in your provided link:

> There is no direct way for us to change the color of the comment
>   indicators quickly and easily, but, the following VBA code can help
>   you to draw a triangular shape overlap each comment indicator with a
>   specific color you need on the active sheet.

This is a very ugly workaround. But using `apache poi` one can do the same. `Apache poi` also provides creating shapes in the drawing layers. Of course there are differences between `HSSF` and `XSSF` to take into account. And the whole thing breaks if someone  changes column widths of cells having the  triangle shapes placed. Then the triangles size also changes. But this is the same with the `VBA` "solution" too.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

class CreateExcelWithComments {

 static void createCellComment(Cell cell, String commentText) {
  // Create the anchor
  CreationHelper creationHelper = cell.getSheet().getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();
  ClientAnchor anchor = creationHelper.createClientAnchor();
  // When the comment box is visible, have it show in a 1 column x 3 rows space
  anchor.setCol1(cell.getColumnIndex() + 1);
  anchor.setCol2(cell.getColumnIndex() + 2);
  anchor.setRow1(cell.getRow().getRowNum());
  anchor.setRow2(cell.getRow().getRowNum() + 3);
  // Create the comment and set the text
  Drawing drawing = cell.getSheet().createDrawingPatriarch();
  Comment comment = drawing.createCellComment(anchor);
  RichTextString richTextString = creationHelper.createRichTextString(commentText);
  comment.setString(richTextString);
  // Assign the comment to the cell
  cell.setCellComment(comment);
 }

 static void createTriangleShapeTopRight(Cell cell, int width, int height, int r, int g, int b) {
  // Get cell width in pixels
  float columnWidth = cell.getSheet().getColumnWidthInPixels(cell.getColumnIndex());
  // Get row heigth in pixels
  float rowHeight = cell.getRow().getHeightInPoints() * Units.PIXEL_DPI / Units.POINT_DPI;
  // Create the anchor
  CreationHelper creationHelper = cell.getSheet().getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();
  ClientAnchor anchor = creationHelper.createClientAnchor();
  // Shape starts top, right - shape width and ends top + shape height, right of the cell
  anchor.setCol1(cell.getColumnIndex());
  if (anchor instanceof XSSFClientAnchor) {
   anchor.setDx1(Math.round((columnWidth - width)) * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL);
  } else if (anchor instanceof HSSFClientAnchor) {
   //see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567203/apache-poi-xssfclientanchor-not-positioning-picture-with-respect-to-dx1-dy1-dx/48607117#48607117 for HSSF
   int DEFAULT_COL_WIDTH = 10 * 256;
   anchor.setDx1(Math.round((columnWidth - width) * Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH / 256f * 14.75f * DEFAULT_COL_WIDTH / columnWidth));
  }
  anchor.setCol2(cell.getColumnIndex() + 1); // left of column index + 1 == right of this cell
  anchor.setDx2(0);
  anchor.setRow1(cell.getRow().getRowNum());
  anchor.setDy1(0);
  anchor.setRow2(cell.getRow().getRowNum());
  if (anchor instanceof XSSFClientAnchor) {
   anchor.setDy2(height * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL);
  } else if (anchor instanceof HSSFClientAnchor) {
   //see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567203/apache-poi-xssfclientanchor-not-positioning-picture-with-respect-to-dx1-dy1-dx/48607117#48607117 for HSSF
   float DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT = 12.75f;
   anchor.setDy2(Math.round(height * Units.PIXEL_DPI / Units.POINT_DPI * 14.75f * DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT / rowHeight));
  }
  // Create the shape
  Drawing drawing = cell.getSheet().createDrawingPatriarch();
  if (drawing instanceof XSSFDrawing) {
   XSSFSimpleShape shape = ((XSSFDrawing)drawing).createSimpleShape((XSSFClientAnchor)anchor);
   shape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.RT_TRIANGLE);
   // Flip the shape horizontal and vertical
   shape.getCTShape().getSpPr().getXfrm().setFlipH(true);
   shape.getCTShape().getSpPr().getXfrm().setFlipV(true);
   // Set color
   shape.setFillColor(r, g, b);
  } else if (drawing instanceof HSSFPatriarch) {
   HSSFSimpleShape shape = ((HSSFPatriarch)drawing).createSimpleShape((HSSFClientAnchor)anchor);
   shape.setShapeType(HSSFShapeTypes.RightTriangle);
   // Flip the shape horizontal and vertical
   shape.setFlipHorizontal(true);
   shape.setFlipVertical(true);
   // Set color
   shape.setFillColor(r, g, b);
   shape.setLineStyle(HSSFShape.LINESTYLE_NONE);
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./Excel.xls";
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./Excel.xlsx";

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  Row row; 
  Cell cell;

  row = sheet.createRow(3);
  cell = row.createCell(5);
  cell.setCellValue("F4");
  sheet.setColumnWidth(cell.getColumnIndex(), 10 * 256);   
  createCellComment(cell, "Cell comment for F4");
  createTriangleShapeTopRight(cell, 10, 10, 0, 255, 0);

  row = sheet.createRow(1);
  cell = row.createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue("B2");
  sheet.setColumnWidth(cell.getColumnIndex(), 10 * 256);   
  createCellComment(cell, "Cell comment for B2");
  createTriangleShapeTopRight(cell, 10, 10, 0, 255, 0);

  try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
   workbook.write(out);
  }

  workbook.close();

 }
}
```